# if (self = [super init]) vs. if ((self = [super init]))

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class, initialization

Was just doing a code review and started to wonder:

I thought `if (self = [super init])` checks whether assigning return value of `[super init]` to variable `self` was successful or not (*value of operation*). Thus `(self = nil)` would actually be `TRUE`.

I thought `if ((self = [super init]))` checks what is the value of `self` after assignment (*value of variable*). Thus `((self = nil))` would be `FALSE`.

Which one is the correct way to use when initialising your own classes? Apple documentation uses the former one ([for example here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocAllocInit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH22-SW4)), which style I'm actually using now.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

They both do the same thing. The thing that the `if` evaluates is the value of the expression inside it, which is the assigned value in an assignment. So when `self` is not nil, you proceed into the `if` block.

The second form throws parens around it to silence any potential compiler warnings about assignments inside conditionals, which is generally bad practice and possibly a typo. But this is idiomatic Objective-C, so it's fine to do it the first way.

Comment: Thanx for clarifying what the expression does - and why I thought there has to be additional parenthesis! Now I recall getting such compiler warnings in other environments and adding second parenthesis (after checking expression really did what I wanted, of course).

Answer (score 13):

As others have said the parentheses don't matter in this case.  Where they do matter is if you explicitly check against nil:

```
if (self = [super init] != nil) // wrong!

if ((self = [super init]) != nil) // right
```

!= has higher precedence than = so in the first case you assign the boolean result of `[super init] != nil` (probably true) to self and then does the test for the if.

Personally, I don't care for either but prefer to do the assignment explicitly outside of the test.  This is a reflection of my programming background that has led me to the belief that booleans are a different type from integers and pointers and that assignments are not expressions, even though, in the case of the C implementation, I am wrong.

```
self = [super init];
if (self != nil)
```

Answer (score 4):

"An assignment expression has the value of the left operand after the assignment" (C99), so either way it has the *value of variable*, as you put it.  The extra parentheses make no difference (except possibly for warnings).