# Basic Objective-C syntax commonly used in init methods

Tags: objective-c, syntax, parentheses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Double parentheses in sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323257/double-parentheses-in-sample-code)

Often the `init` method in an Objective-C class will have the following line:

```
if ((self = [super init])) { ...
```

I'm just wondering if the extra parentheses are necessary. Is the following line equivalent?

```
if (self = [super init]) { ...
```

**Edit:** This is indeed a duplicate of [Double parentheses in sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323257/double-parentheses-in-sample-code)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Double parentheses in sample code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323257/), [if (self = \[super init\]) vs. if ((self = \[super init\]))](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059232/). Related: [XCode 4 if (self = \[super init\]) issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344810/), [if(self = \[super init\]) - LLVM warning! How are you dealing with it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940366/)

Answer (score 3):

They are not necessary, but using `((` and `))` say "yes, I mean an assignment, not a comparison."

In fact clang will warn you about using assignment in an if condition and suggest double parentheses for unambiguity.

In general I think this could be considered bad coding style, but an exception is made here since this is a special frequently used pattern in obj-c

Comment: It is necessary if you compile with -Werror like a lot of of people do.