# The correct way to call [super init]

Tags: ios, objective-c, initialization

I just found this code in an article:

```
- (id)init
{
  if (self = [super init])
  {
      someProperty = @"Some Value";
  }

  return self;
}
```

However, I usually do it like this:

```
- (id)init
{
  self = [super init];

  if (self)
  {
      someProperty = @"Some Value";
  }

  return self;
}
```

And even if I do as in the first case, I do add some extra parentheses:

```
- (id)init
{
  if ((self = [super init]))
  {
      someProperty = @"Some Value";
  }

  return self;
}
```

I know this is the correct (or recommended way) to do it, but I do not remember why.

Can someone explain me the difference between:

```
if ((self = [super init]))
```

and

```
if (self = [super init])
```

?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See also [Basic ObjC syntax commonly used in init methods](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12644657), and the links I left there earlier.

Comment: Glad I could be helpful.