# Objective-C self variable check

Tags: objective-c, initialization

I am reading the Cocoa Design Patterns books. In the books, after assigning the `self` variable, it is checked whether `self` is `nil` like below

```
if( nil != self){
// code
}
```

I have also seen another way of checking the self like

```
if( self ){ 
// code 
}
```

Is there any benefit for using either of these techniques or is it just a matter of preference?

Thanks.

Comment: go throgh this http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/198477-self-super-init-debate.html#198477

Comment: possible duplicate of [if (self = \[super init\]) vs. if ((self = \[super init\]))](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059232/if-self-super-init-vs-if-self-super-init)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### They're the same

The contents of an `if` block

```
if (expression) {
    // contents...
}
```

are executed just in case the `expression` evaluates to a non-zero value.

This means that the code in the following `if` block

```
//the first if block
if (self) {
    // contents....
}
```

will execute whenever `self` is non-zero.

Meanwhile, the contents of *this* `if` block

```
// the second if block
if (self != nil) {
    // contents...
}
```

are executed whenever `self != nil` is non-zero.

The operator `!=` returns `0` in the case that the two comparands (in this case `self` and `nil`) are identical and returns `1` in the case that the two comparands are not identical.  So the code in the second `if` block will execute whenever `self` is not identical to `nil`.

But `nil` is `#define`d to be `0` in `<objc/objc.h>`.  Thus the code in the second `if` block will execute whenever `self` is not identical to `0`.  This is exactly the same time that the code in the first `if` block executes: whenever `self` is non-zero.

#### The upshot

Since the two approaches result in exactly the same code being executed, there are no technical reasons to prefer one to the other.  The most important stylistic consideration in this case is **consistency** in your initializers.  Decide which style you prefer and use it everywhere.